# Generating Controller Gen with Kubebuilder

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder

I am trying to build out my Custom Resource project in Kubebuilder but it seems like I am missing my controller gen whenever I build it out. I keep getting the error:

```
/Users/*****/Kubernetes/postgres-writer-operator/bin/controller-gen object:headerFile="hack/boilerplate.go.txt" paths="./..."
bash: /Users/****/Kubernetes/postgres-writer-operator/bin/controller-gen: No such file or directory
make: *** [generate] Error 127
Error: failed to create API: unable to run post-scaffold tasks of "base.go.kubebuilder.io/v3": exit status 2
Usage:
  kubebuilder create api [flags]
```

I am new to Kubernetes and am following the tutorial below:
https://yash-kukreja-98.medium.com/develop-on-kubernetes-series-operator-dev-understanding-and-dissecting-kubebuilder-4321d3ecd7d6

First I ran the following command that bootstraps my project:

```
kubebuilder init \
--domain yash.com \
--repo github.com/yashvardhan-kukreja/postgres-writer-operator \
--project-name postgres-writer-operator \
--license apache2 \
--skip-go-version-check
```

After running the command I went into my directory and found the following files and folders:
[image]

Then the next step was to run bootstrapper for my custom resource PostgresWriter and attach it to the operator.

```
kubebuilder create api \
--group demo \
--version v1 \
--kind PostgresWriter \
--resource true \
--controller true \
--namespaced true
```

This resulted in the error listed above. How do I generate my controller gen using kubebuilder? Is there a step I am missing here?

FYI by go version is 1.18.

Comment: did you get chance to review this : https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/1319

Answer (score 7):

Not a perfect solution, this should work with the latest go version but it doesn't, so I had to downgrade the go version to 1.17 and then it worked

Summarizing what I learned from this article on downgrading your go version.
https://blog.notmyhostna.me/posts/downgrade-go-installed-with-homebrew/

Install version 1.17 go

```
brew install go@1.17
```

You will still see that the version didn't change, so you need to unlink the current version by running

```
brew unlink go
```

Now you can link the 1.17 version of Go, so when you do go version you'll get 1.17.

```
brew link --force go@1.17
```

Voila! You should now see that your current version is 1.17 and you'll be able to successfully run Kubebuilder.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue and resetting my go version to v1.17.* helped me resolve the issue.

Step 1: Uninstall go by finding out where go is located  `$ which go`
Step 2: Remove any go related paths from PATH environment variable
Step 3: Re install go using the pkg in this [link](https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.8.darwin-amd64.pkg).

Try all your kubebuilder steps once again after go installation is complete.

Comment: Thank you! This was the right track, I am using a mac so I followed the instructions around using Homebrew to downgrade my go version. https://blog.notmyhostna.me/posts/downgrade-go-installed-with-homebrew/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing.